# tee command with append mode giving error from mysql command line

Tags: mysql, linux

When I am trying to execute below command from the mysql command line client on a linux machine

```
mysql> tee -a /data/lib/rc.txt;
```

it gives me the following error even though file rc.txt already exists

> mysql: Can't create/write to file '-a /data/lib/rc.txt' (Errcode: 2)

Comment: What are the permissions set to on the file you are trying to access?

Comment: i have given full rights to file

Answer (score 2):

MySQL `tee` always appends: `-a` flag is neither necessary nor supported (and thus `mysql` is treating `-a /data/lib/rc.txt` as your filename, hence the error).

See [mysql Commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-commands.html).

Comment: so it means if i have file containing data and i am trying to append content into it , mysql will allow appending result set into file without overwriting it

Comment: @user1409935 Yes, MySQL will append the result and not overwrite anything by default. Getting rid of the '-a' will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this  logging is works perfect here in `mysql`

```
mysql> tee /data/lib/rc.txt;
```

After executing this command you could find the file in `location` and then try simple commands you could find the output  logged in `rc.txt` file and `appending`  will be taken place automatically on next `commands` , works fine `mysql 5.1`  . Note no need to pass parameter in command for appending  use simple as same.

to disable logging you are supposed to use the `notee`

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_tee)